# Restrict WebAuthn credential to specific website

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy, webauthn

I just starting playing around with `WebAuthn` on localhost. I'm wondering if there is a way to restrict a credential for auth on a specific origin / website. Is that already the case or can anyone with the public key just call `navigator.credentials.get` on any host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two levels of controls that prevent passkeys from being used on the wrong website:

“RP” stands for “relying party”. You (the website) are a “relying party” in authentication-speak. An RP ID is a domain name and every passkey has one that’s fixed at creation time. Every passkey operation asserts an RP ID and, if a passkey’s RP ID doesn’t match, then it doesn’t exist for that operation.

This prevents one site from using another’s passkeys. A passkey with an RP ID of foo.com can’t be used on bar.com because bar.com can’t assert an RP ID of foo.com. A site may use any RP ID formed by discarding zero or more labels from the left of its domain name until it hits an eTLD. So say that you’re https://www.foo.co.uk: you can assert [www.foo.co.uk](http://www.foo.co.uk) (discarding zero labels), foo.co.uk (discarding one label), but not co.uk because that hits an eTLD. If you don’t set an RP ID in a request then the default is the site’s full domain.

Our [www.foo.co.uk](http://www.foo.co.uk) example might happily be creating passkeys with the default RP ID but later decide that it wants to move all sign-in activity to an isolated origin, https://accounts.foo.co.uk. But none of the passkeys could be used from that origin! If would have needed to create them with an RP ID of foo.co.uk in the first place to allow that.

But you might want to be careful about always setting the most general RP ID because then usercontent.foo.co.uk could access and overwrite them too. That brings us to the second control mechanism: when a passkey is used to sign in, the browser includes the origin that made the request in the signed data. So accounts.foo.co.uk would be able to see that a request was triggered by usercontent.foo.co.uk and reject it, even if the passkey’s RP ID allowed usercontent.foo.co.uk to use it. But that mechanism can’t do anything about usercontent.foo.co.uk being able to overwrite them.

Comment: Great answer thanks! I was aware of the second method you mentioned that depends on server side verifying the signature data. But the primary method is far more important as you clearly explained. Just curious, so when I'm running on localhost its storing localhost or localhost:port in the RP ID? I suppose on deployment to an actual TLD it will be easier for me to test and see the exact settings. Good to know ahead that the URL scheme would be a pain to change later on and needs to be set correctly from the start :)

Comment: An RP ID is just a domain name: no scheme nor port. So it would be "localhost".

Answer (score 2):

WebAuthn credentials are origin-bound by design, which is one of the reasons they are phishing resistant credentials.